# jquery select a class within an <i> italics tag that is within an <a> anchor tag

Tags: jquery, html, dom, select

I have to select all anchor tags on the page that have its text wrapped in an i tag which has the class pdf.

```html
<a href="somewebsite.com"><i class="pdf"> </i>this is the text</a>
```

I have this and it seems to be wrong:

```js
$( "a>i" ).each (function() {
  $(this).find(".pdf");
  alert("This is a PDF icon in an <i> tag");
});
```

The alert seems to hit twice the amount of times or something.

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or check if the `<i>` has the class by making a small adjustment to your script:

```
$("a>i").each(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass("pdf") {
        alert("This is a PDF icon in an <i> tag");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the [jQuery `:has` selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/):

```
$("a:has(i.pdf)")
```

Depending on what your goal is, you may not need to use `.each()` at all. For example, if you wanted to turn those links red...

```js
$("a:has(i.pdf)").css("color", "red");
```

```css
a{display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="somewebsite.com"><i class="pdf"></i>this has &lt;i class="pdf"&gt;</a>
<a href="somewebsite.com"><i class="pdf"></i>this has &lt;i class="pdf"&gt;</a>
<a href="somewebsite.com">this does not have &lt;i class="pdf"&gt;</a>
<a href="somewebsite.com"><i class="pdf"></i>this has &lt;i class="pdf"&gt;</a>
```